# Check checkbox from database values

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have two tables in a database. In reports I am storing info for reports and in report_roles I am assigning which user can access the report.

```
reports
+--+-----------+---------------+
|id|report_name|report_filename|
+--+-----------+---------------+
|13|Report 1   |reportname1    |
|14|Report 2   |reportname2    |
|15|Report 3   |reportname3    |
+--+-----------+---------------+

report_roles
+---------+-------+
|report_id|user_id|
+---------+-------+
|14       |1      |
|13       |1      |
|14       |2      |
|13       |2      |
+---------+-------+
```

I want to display all the reports from table reports with checkboxes and check only those which are added in the report_roles associated with the user id. This is the code I am running:

```
        $id = $_POST['user_id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM reports LEFT JOIN report_roles ON report_roles.report_id = reports.id";

        $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
        if (!$sql) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));
            exit();
        }

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) { 
            if ($row['user_id'] == $id) { 

            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='" . ($row['id'])  . "'" . "id='" . ($row['id'])  . "'" . "value='yes'" . ($row['user_id'] == $id ? 'checked' : '') .">";
            echo $row['report_name'];
            } else {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='" . ($row['id'])  . "'" . "id='" . ($row['id'])  . "'" . "value='yes'" . ">";
            echo $row['report_name']; 
            }

        }
```

If $id = 1 I am receiving this:

```
|checked| Report2   |checked| Report 1   |unchecked| Report2   |unchecked| Report 1   |unchecked| Report3
```

Which is completely right based on the code I wrote. I cannot figure out how to display all the reports without duplicates from reports table and check only those which are available in report_roles, something like this:

```
|checked| Report2   |checked| Report 1  |unchecked| Report3
```

I am sure I have to change my query with the join. Tried to do accomplish this task with two separate queries without joins but with no luck. Hope someone can help.

Comment: you can specify the fields that you want to get. So you can write SELECT report_roles.* - then you get only fields from this table. Also you can specify the id you want to get in the query. so you not must test it in php.
"SELECT report_roles.* FROM reports LEFT JOIN report_roles ON report_roles.report_id = reports.id AND id = $id"

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was just missing a statement in my query and thanks to Bernd Buffed I realized that I have to add one AND at the end of the query and it should look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM reports LEFT JOIN report_roles ON report_roles.report_id = reports.id AND user_id = $id";
```

Till now I was adding WHERE user_id = $id and was receiving only those reports which exists in report_roles. With the AND I am receiving all reports from reports table and my script can check only those which are in report_roles based on a simple php check.